# Increment HTML table row through php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

What am doing is basically there is list for example
-thing1
-thing2
-thing3
-thing4

and each has an ADD button beside it 
when i press the add button it goes through a function and pops up a Html table row 
now i want when i press Add button for thing2 it should increment row in html table instead of overwriting it HELP PLS!!

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
      $id = $row['id'];
       echo "<tr style=background-color:#005566;color:white;>";
        //echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
        echo "<td >".$row['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td >".$row['description']."</td>";
        echo "<td >".$row['quantity']."</td>";
        echo "<td >".$row['price']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='index.php?record=$id' class='btn btn-info' style=background-color:#005566;border:none;>ADD+</a></td>";

      // echo "<td><a href='medicine_delete.php?id=$id' style=color:white;text-decoration:none;>Delete</a> / <a href='medicine_update.php?edit=$id' style=color:white;text-decoration:none;>Edit</a></td>";


    }

    echo "</table>";
        if (isset($_GET['record'])) {

    displa_cart();

}
```

THE FUNCTION IS

```
function displa_cart(){
        $id=$_GET['record'];
        global $dbc;enter code here
        $q=mysql_query("SELECT name,quantity FROM medicine where id='$id'");
        $num=mysql_num_rows($q);
        while ($fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
            echo "<form method='post' action='updaterecord.php'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'><table class='table table-bordered' style='width:35%;position: relative;left: 250px;bottom: 340px;''>
                    <thead>
                        <tr class=info>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>"; 

                    echo "<tr><td>".$fetch['name']."</td>"."<td><input type=text name='qty' maxlength=3 value='$fetch[quantity]'></td></tr><br>";
                    echo "<tr><td><input type=submit value='Checkout'></td><td><input type=submit  value='update'></td></tr>";



        }

    echo "</table></form>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My question for you is, why do you create new table inside while loop every iteration and end it outside? isn't it the problem?